# Having trouble with basic but secure login system using PHP and MySQL

Tags: php, html, mysql, sql, validation

- I am using Wamp,

  - myown pc as localhost
  - Port:80
  - i have saved files of php script in as usual default location
    `C:\wamp\www\webservice`
  - I have created a config file for php access i have called it as
    `config.inc.php`
  - I have created mysql database with credentials `username=dev,
    password=root, databasename=webservice`

***Code for it is below here::***

```
<?php 

    // These variables define the connection information for your MySQL database 
    $username = "dev"; 
    $password = "root"; 
    $host = "localhost"; 
    $dbname = "webservice"; 


    $options = array(PDO::MYSQL_ATTR_INIT_COMMAND => 'SET NAMES utf8'); 

    try 
    { 

        $db = new PDO("mysql:host={$host};dbname={$dbname};charset=utf8", $username, $password, $options); 
    } 
    catch(PDOException $ex) 
    { 

        die("Failed to connect to the database: " . $ex->getMessage()); 
    } 
    $db->setAttribute(PDO::ATTR_ERRMODE, PDO::ERRMODE_EXCEPTION);  
    $db->setAttribute(PDO::ATTR_DEFAULT_FETCH_MODE, PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);    
    if(function_exists('get_magic_quotes_gpc') && get_magic_quotes_gpc()) 
    { 
        function undo_magic_quotes_gpc(&$array) 
        { 
            foreach($array as &$value) 
            { 
                if(is_array($value)) 
                { 
                    undo_magic_quotes_gpc($value); 
                } 
                else 
                { 
                    $value = stripslashes($value); 
                } 
            } 
        }      
        undo_magic_quotes_gpc($_POST); 
        undo_magic_quotes_gpc($_GET); 
        undo_magic_quotes_gpc($_COOKIE); 
    } 
    header('Content-Type: text/html; charset=utf-8'); 
    session_start(); 
?>
```

---

**then i have created a simple test for the functionality using a script file named `register.php`**

---

*code for it is given below::*

---

```
<?php

require ("config.inc.php");

?>

<h1>Register</h1>
<form action="register.php" method="post">
    Username:<br/>
    <input type="text" name="username" placeholder="user name"><br/>
    Password:<br/>
    <input type="password" name="username" placeholder="user name"><br/>
    <input type="submit" value="Register user"/>
</form>
```

when i run from my browser `http://localhost/webservice/register.php`

---

I get this error in the browser displayed as

**Failed to connect to the database: SQLSTATE[28000] [1045] Access denied for user 'dev'@'localhost' (using password: YES)**

---

Please any suggestions on how to overcome this

Comment: The error is pretty self explanatory. Either you entered wrong credentials or you failed to configure properly your database. Look at how the PDO contructor is used : http://www.php.net/manual/fr/pdo.construct.php

Comment: Try 'root' as username?

Answer (score 0):

Please don't use root for security reason. Maybe the user was not good configure. Look at this documentation too http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/create-user.html.

Furthermore, I saw in your code that session_start() is call at the end of the script, if an error occured like this before, PHP will print the error and not start session so you should use it at the beginning of the script.

Hope it helps.